# .net 6 and Redis cache integration using sets , hashes

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, stackexchange.redis

.net 6 and Redis cache integration using sets , hashes.
Please provide source code for this.
Use latest stack exchange library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple save demo, you can take a look:

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
    options.Configuration = "127.0.0.1:6379";
});
builder.Services.AddSession(); 

app.UseSession();
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

        public TestController(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
        {
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("test")]
        public void Test()
        {      
            const string key = "message";
            const string value = "hello";
            _distributedCache.SetString(key, value);


        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

For more examples, you can refer to this article：

[Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-6.0#distributed-redis-cache)

Comment: If I want to use SETADD method. Is it possible using IDistributedCache ?